# Bootstrap tabcollapse not working for jquery call on small screens

Tags: html, jquery, angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

Below I added that bootstrap-tabcollapse plugin. In the big screen it seems to work well, however in the small screen it doesn't show anything, even I resize it appear. I used the [bootstrap plugin](https://github.com/flatlogic/bootstrap-tabcollapse).where can I need to change the jquery plugin. Can anyone help me, Thanks !

```html
<script src="https://github.com/flatlogic/bootstrap-tabcollapse/blob/master/bootstrap-tabcollapse.js"></script>
```

> html nav-tab

```html
 <div class="date-tabs-container setup-accordion-container">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="reviewerSetupTabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" id="reviewersTab" href="#primary">Primary Reviewers</a></li>
        <li (click)="getReassignmentData()"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-2">Reassignment Options</a></li>
        <li (click)="selectedPermissionTab = 'primary';getReviewerPermissionsData()"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-3">Permissions</a></li>
        <li (click)="resetNotificationFields('reset')"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-4">Notifications</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally I have resolved this problem by changing window width**

```
 TabCollapse.prototype.checkState = function(){
    if ((this.$tabs.is(':visible') && this._accordionVisible) || $(window).width() > 767){
        this.showTabs();
        this._accordionVisible = false;
    } else if ((this.$accordion.is(':visible') && !this._accordionVisible) || $(window).width() < 768){
        this.showAccordion();
        this._accordionVisible = true;
    }
};
```